# vba, sum based on column header

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help with VBA!
I want to write a code that will sum the "sales" column in different 7 sheets. The problem is that the column has a different location in each sheet and a dinamic rows' count. The sum should be in the last row + 1.

I am not very good at macros, but I guess I should start with checking i to 7 sheets. Then I should sum a range based on the header ("Sales"). I am lost about how to write all of this..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub SumSales()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rngS As Range, lastRow As Long
  For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets 'iterate through all sheets
    'find the cell having "Sales" text/value
    Set rngS = sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(1, _
        sh.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).Find("Sales")
    'if the cell has been found (the cell range is NOT Nothing...)
    If Not rngS Is Nothing Then
        'Determine the last row of the found cell column:
        lastRow = sh.Cells(Rows.count, rngS.Column).End(xlUp).row
        'Write the Sum formula in the last empty cell:
        rngS.Offset(lastRow).formula = "=Sum(" & rngS.Offset(1).address & _
             ":" & sh.Cells(lastRow, rngS.Column).address & ")"
        sh.Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Value = "Sum of sales is:"
    Else
        'if any cell has been found, it returns in Immediate Window (Being in VBE, Ctrl + G) the sheet names not having "Sales" header:
        Debug.Print "No ""Sales"" column in sheet """ & sh.name & """."
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: OH MY GOD YES!!!! Could you please explain what did you do here? Especially the IF and ELSE part..

Comment: Yes. But now I am driving... ;)

Comment: Also, I have several other sheets in that file that have nothing to do with the sales. can I order excel to examine the specific 7 sheets?
I don't mind putting a button on the 1st of then and tell exam to examine the following 6.

Comment: HAHA no worries! Drive safe!

Comment: @gohog69950: Commented the code lines in order to be easily understood (I think...). I also adapted the code to work only for some specific worksheet names. If the code answers the question, we here tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar will know that the code works... :)

Comment: you are so awesome! i have one last question haha.. I want to write "Sum of sales is:" at the same row as rhe sum (can be on the first column). where should i add that code?

Comment: @gohog69950: Not sure I understand what you need... Do you mean, on the same row with the Sum, to write "Sum of sales is:", in column A:A? If yes, I adapted the code to also do that. If not, please better explain what you mean...